# How to reverse CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make this exact transition to reverse.
Div Two has a delay so it doesn't become visible before Div One is completely gone.
What I want is that if you click on button Two when Div Two is visible, Div Two disappears after that div One appears. So exactly the reverse of the transition.

```js
var One = document.getElementById("one");
var Two = document.getElementById("two");

function actionOne() {
  one.style.height = "0px";
  two.style.height = "200px";
}

function actionTwo() {  
  one.style.height = "200px";
  two.style.height = "0px";
}
```

```css
#one {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: 2s;
}

#two {
  background: pink;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: 2s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
} 

p {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="actionOne()">Button One</button>
<button onclick="actionTwo()">Button Two</button>  

<div id="one">
  <p>Div One</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p>Div Two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the delay when clicking on the button accordingly

See code snippet:

```js
var One = document.getElementById("one");
var Two = document.getElementById("two");

function actionOne() {
  one.style.height = "0px";
  two.style.height = "200px";

  one.style.transitionDelay = '0s';
  two.style.transitionDelay = '2s';
}

function actionTwo() {
  one.style.height = "200px";
  two.style.height = "0px";

  one.style.transitionDelay = '2s';
  two.style.transitionDelay = '0s';
}
```

```css
#one {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
}

#two {
  background: pink;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

p {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="actionOne()">Button One</button>
<button onclick="actionTwo()">Button Two</button>

<div id="one">
  <p>Div One</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p>Div Two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var One = document.getElementById("one");
var Two = document.getElementById("two");

function actionOne() {

  one.style.height = "0px";
  two.style.height = "200px";
  
}

function actionTwo() {  
  two.style.height = "0px";
  one.style.height = "200px";
}
```

```css
#one {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: 2s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#two {
  background: pink;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: 2s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
} 

p {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="actionOne()">Button One</button>
<button onclick="actionTwo()">Button Two</button>  

<div id="one">
  <p>Div One</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p>Div Two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would've used this if in my project the divs were the same height. This solution looks really odd when the divs aren't identical to each other.